# TfidfVectorizer shrinks my datafreame from 799 to 3

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have dataframe that has text columns

and multilabel values

RepID, RepText,                                     Code
1      This is a test. thanks for purchasing...     Fruit, Meat
2      Purchased Milk, and Bananas, I also p...     Dairy, Fruit, Others

Here is my code

```
######## df has 1000 records

multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_binarizer.fit(df['Code'])
y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(df['Code'])
X = df[df.columns.difference(["Code"])]

######## df split into X (RepID, RepText)
######## and y (Code)


xtrain, xval, ytrain, yval = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=9)

##### xtrain.shape = (800,3)
##### xval.shape = (200,3)
##### ytrain.shape = (800,1725)
##### yval.shape = (200,1725)


tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=10000)
xtrain_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(xtrain)
xval_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(xval)

##### But after the code above
##### xtrain_tfidf.shape = (3,3)
##### xval_tfidf.shape = (3,3)
##### ytrain.shape = (800,1725)
##### yval.shape = (200,1725)

##### when means when I do the next line

xval_tfidf.shape

#mdl = LinearRegression()
mdl = LogisticRegression()
#mdl = SVC(gamma='auto', probability=True)
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(mdl)
clf.fit(xtrain_tfidf, ytrain)
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 799]
```

Why? why am I getting only **3 records** instead of **800** after *TfidfVectorizer* lines?

When I tried to view what is in *xtrain_tfidf*, I got this

```
xtrain_tfidf
Out[56]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason

I forgot to choose only text column in splitting records

```
xtrain, xval, ytrain, yval = train_test_split(X["RepText"], y, test_size=0.2, random_state=9)
```